# Unable to map byte[] or byte[]? (nullable byte[]) using AutoMapper ForCtorParam function

Tags: c#, automapper, mapper, nullable-reference-types, automapper-6

### Unable to map byte[] or byte[]? (nullable byte[]) using AutoMapper ForCtorParam function, I am getting below error message

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException :  Unmapped members were
> found. Review the types and members below. Add a custom mapping
> expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the
> source/destination type For no matching constructor, add a no-arg
> ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
> ================================================================================== Model -> ModelDto (Destination member list)
> AutoMapperForCtorParamTest+Model ->
> AutoMapperForCtorParamTest+ModelDto (Destination member list) Unmapped
> properties: Code LinkId

Sample code to recreate below

```
public class AutoMapperForCtorParamTest
    {
        private readonly IMapper mapper;

        public AutoMapperForCtorParamTest()
        {
            mapper = new Mapper(new MapperConfiguration(
                cfg =>
                    {
                        cfg.AddProfile<ModelMapperProfile>();
                    }));
        }

        [Fact]
        public void MapAllProperties()
        {
            mapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }

        public class ModelMapperProfile : Profile
        {
            public ModelMapperProfile()
            {
                var defaultCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();

                CreateMap<Model, ModelDto>()
                    .ForCtorParam("type", cfg => cfg.MapFrom(x => 1))
                    .ForCtorParam("code", cfg => cfg.MapFrom<byte[]>(x => defaultCode))
                    .ForCtorParam("linkId", cfg => cfg.MapFrom<byte[]?>(x => null));
            }
        }

        public class ModelDto
        {
            public ModelDto(int id, string name, int type, byte[] code, byte[]? linkId)
            {
                Id = id;
                Name = name;
                Type = type;
                Code = code;
                LinkId = linkId;
            }

            public int Id { get; }

            public string Name { get; }

            public int Type { get; }

            public byte[] Code { get; }

            public byte[]? LinkId { get; }
        }

        public class Model
        {
            public Model(int id, string name)
            {
                Id = id;
                Name = name;
            }

            public int Id { get; }

            public string Name { get; }
        }
    }
```

Note:

1. I am using dotnet core 3.1 with nullable types enabled
2. I don't want to use construct using or convert using functions
3. I am using Automapper v 10.0.0

Comment: I reproduced the issue [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZAJWJF). I added the two missing ctor params and ignore to both missed properties because they're mappt by ctor. This "solves" the configuration check error but it does not behave as expected because `LinkId` contains an empty array instead of `null`.

Comment: The problem is solve using `this.AllowNullCollections = true;` in profile ctor.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian Schumann, That does work as expected, but looks a bit odd as a member has been mapped and ignored in the same config. Is this the recommended way or a workaround ?

Comment: The member itself is not mapped. There is a mapping for ctor param. But it is a workarround. That's the reason why I don't add this as answer because I don't understand why the same thing is working for the `Type` property. This property doesn't need to be ignored but looks the same like `Code` or `LinkId`. Only the types are different. But if a mapping is needed for each property there also should be an ignore (or mapping) for `Type`. I don't realy understand that behaviour and hope there will be anyone who ansers this question and describes that wired fact.

Comment: Yes I agree the issue is with byte[], ForCtorParam map works for other types. Anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you should add a constructor with those defaults. It seems a lot cleaner that all that code in the AM config.

Comment: @MaheshTalreja I got it. I missread your code. There is an automated mapping created because CreateMap is not called using `(MemberList.None)`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu How does this change the behaviour of AutoMapper? See [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uYrNd4). The problem still remains. Using a `MemberList.None` will solve the issue but it does not explain why it is working for property `Type`.

Comment: `Type` has no setter so is ignored. Collections don't need setters to be mapped.

Comment: @MaheshTalreja The best solution I found so far is [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lVk69V) using `MemberList.None` and map all the ctor params. But I'm still missing an explanation for the wired `Type` behaviour.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I don't get the point. I might understand that properties without setters are ignored. But if that's true why doesn't this also work for collection? A `byte[]` is a collection but there's nothing that enforces that it supplies enough space to collect all source items.

Comment: Probably then it fails at runtime. The fact remains that you don't need a setter to map a collection. Hopefully that's obvious :)

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3449#issuecomment-651522397

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
.ForCtorParam("text", opt => opt.MapFrom<byte[]?>(src => null));
```

In my case (string) I fixed it with:

```
.ForCtorParam("text", opt => opt.MapFrom<string>(src => null));
```